# How do print a field of 20x20 with the coordinates of the 50 objects in the right 'boxes' (Java)

Tags: java, coordinates, field

So I have recently been busy with creating a number of worlds with using 50 objects in a world of 400 tiles.

Here is the code of a method that initializes the array of 50 objects with random coordinates, then checks the duplicates - depending on the value of the parameter, it does this for that amount of times, I put in 1000000 to get a good probability calculation so it runs this method 1000000 times. -  Here is the code:

```
public void initializeAndExecute(int runAmount) {
    tiles = new String[49]; //array size

    for (int k = 0; k < runAmount; k++) { //amount of generating new array
        for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) { //put 50 objects in array
            tile = new Tile();
            tiles[i] = (tile.printXandY()); //put coordinates at this index
        }//eind for
        checkDupes(); //check collisions
        if (duplicates != 0) { //if collision , counter++, duplicates reset.
            runWithCollision++; //for probability calculation
            duplicates = 0;
        }
        run++; //run always ++ even if no duplicates, voor probability calculation.
    }
}
```

So what I want to do now is have a field of 400 tiles (20x20) and depending on the coordinates put a [*] if an object is equal to that position in the field. If there is more than one object on the same spot do something like [**]. Here is the code of my **field()** method:

```
public void field() {


    for (int p = 0; p < 20; p++) { //for 20 rows
        for (int o = 0; o < 19; o++) { //to fill rows
            if (tile.getX() == o && tile.getY() == p) {
                System.out.print("[*]");
            } else {
                System.out.print("[_]");
            }
            if (o == 18) {
                System.out.println("[_]"); //newline
            }
        }
    }
```

This isn't working obviously, but it was to test how it would look like, it only prints one coordinate as it is not dynamically executed in the    **initializeAndExecute()** method.

Any ideas? Maybe a 2-dimensional array? (which I have no idea of how to implement it)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: first: tiles = new String[49]; i thought you want create 50 objects? second: do you store your coordinates as string? tiles[i] = (tile.printXandY()); maybe you should put your tiles in a tile-array? tiles = new Tile[50];

Comment: And how would you put them in the field with the exact coordinates then?

Comment: something like: tiles[i] = new Tile(x, y); the Tile-Object know his coordinates, so if you want to check it later, just iterate over tiles-Array and use tile.getX()

Comment: How would I print a field on output like [][][][][] and putting the objects in them depending on the coordinates of it. There will be 400 tiles, and 50 objects with coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make a Tile-Array for your objects:

```
public void initializeAndExecute(int runAmount) {
   tiles = new Tile[50]; //array size, 50!!!

   for (int k = 0; k < runAmount; k++) { //amount of generating new array
       for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { //put 50 objects in array
           tiles[i] = new Tile(); //constructor creates random coordinates
       }
       ...
   }
}
```

you can make a method to check if an Object is on field:

```
public boolean objectIsOnField(int x, int y){
    for(int i = 0;i < tiles.length;i++){
        Tile t = tiles[i];
        if(t.getX() == x && t.getY() == y)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

now you can use the check-method in your print-method:

```
public void printField(){
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < 20;j++){
            if(objectIsOnField(j, i)) //j is for x because j iterate through line
                System.out.print("[*]");
            else
                System.out.print("[_]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

i actually dont really understand, why do you want to run the initialization 100000 times... do you try to avoid collisions? if so you could save used coordinates and simply create new coordinate, if you see that the one coordinate you have just created is already used

Comment: And I ran it a million times to get a good probability calculation of duplicates

Comment: i guess its ok, as long as you really need this information:)